# Is it possible to allow a normal user to create and manage virtual machines of windows (Hyper-V)?

Tags: windows, hyper-v

I would like to allow to a normal user (non admin ser) to can create and manage virtual machines with Hyper-V administrator.

I have added the user to the gruop Hyper-V administrator, but still I don't have permissions to create virtual machines.

So I would like to know if there is some way to allow to a normal user to can manage it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a standard user on Win10 21H2 and I can create VMs in Hyper-V. All I did was add myself to the group hyper-v administrators.

The only thing that does not work, is to mount physical drives in a VM - that is something, only admins may do.

Please make sure that after you added yourself to that group, you logged off and on again.